# PYTHON/SQL Delete data from table to manage database

Tags: python, sql

I couldn't find answer for my question anywhere.

Could you please help me to write the `delete_data` method to delete data from the table. The user will input the employee id to delete this record.

```py
sql_delete_data = "DELETE from NOA where EmployeeId=?"    

def delete_data(self):
    try:
        self.get_connection()
        if result.rowcount != 0:
            print (str(result.rowcount)+ "Row(s) affected.")
        else:
            print ("Record can not find in the database")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally: 
        self.conn.close()
```

Comment: I don't follow the code setup at all. You have a disembodied method (but don't show the class), some query string in the global scope, and no `execute()` to actually try run the query

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
id_for_deletion = (42,)

def delete_data(self):
    try:
      self.get_connection()
      # Get a cursor from the connection
      cursor = self.conn.cursor()
      # Execute the SQL statement on the cursor
      result = cursor.execute(sql_delete_data, id_for_deletion)
      # Commit (save) the result
      self.conn.commit()

      if result.rowcount != 0:
        print (str(result.rowcount)+ "Row(s) affected.")
      else:
        print ("Record can not find in the database")

    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      # Rollback changes on error
      self.conn.rollback()
    finally: 
      self.conn.close()
```